# Verification: using polar coordinates correctly?$\int_Kx^2(x^2+y^2)\mathop{d(x,y)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Doing some old exam questions, this popped up:
Calculate 
$$\int_Kx^2(x^2+y^2)\mathop{d(x,y)}$$
where 
$$K = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\vert x^2+y^2\le 1\}$$
I'm sure polar coordinates are the way to go, so the integral is equal to:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}r^4\cos^2(\varphi)r\mathop{drd\varphi}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$
(checked with calculator)

I'm unsure because WA says that 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x^2(x^2+y^2)\mathop{dydx} = \frac{\pi}{24}$$

Am I using polar coordinates correctly? Did I make some other mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the domain of second integral is only a quarter circle, so both of the answers are correct.

Comment: For OP: always draw the regions that the limits correspond to. It will help you decide if you made a mistake, someone else did, or if there is only a mistake at a symmetry level (like in this case.. only 1/4 of the region was being considered).